# How to manage root actions in batch script triggered by an SSH

Tags: c, linux, unix, ssh, sh

Ok, here is a tricky question:

First, I have a very small C application that runs in an Unix machine. This application gets two arguments and tries to execute an .sh file in a Linux (Ubuntu) machine, like this:

`./myapp luke leia`

Ok, now the C code executes more or less this:

```
char temp[512];
sprintf(temp, "ssh user@server \"sh \\$HOME/save.sh %s %s\"", argv[1], argv[2]);
system((char *)temp);
```

As you can see, it opens a connection to my Linux server and executes a batch script in the home folder of my 'user'. This is how it looks like when I try directly in my terminal:

`ssh user@server "sh \$HOME/save.sh luke leia"`

In my Unix side, I am asked for a password for the SSH, and it works just fine. I get all the echoes from the save.sh file in my Unix machine and it works well, except if I need a sudo permission. So I tried this in my server:

1. Using `sudo visudo` in the server, below the line that says `%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL` I put:

   `%user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/user/save.sh`
2. My save.sh looks like this:

> ```
> #! /bin/bash
> sudo echo "[save action] args: ${1} , ${2}" >> /somewhere/save.log;
> echo "${1} and ${2} are brother and sister.";
> ```

1. My folder "somewhere" belongs to root, so normally my 'user' can't save it. So I changed the code in my application to handle this command instead:

`ssh user@server "sudo sh \$HOME/save.sh luke leia"`

Now I get this error:

`sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Which is the best way to trigger this script using sudo and not being prompted with root password? I tried using `-t`, but is asks for root password. Any thoughts?

Comment: as a side note, please use snprintf instead of sprintf in your c code - snippet that you provided is a classical example of bufer overflow vulnerability, where you write not sanitized user data to stack based buffer.

Comment: I changed my code, thanks for the note!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that comes to my mind is to provide the root passowrd of "server" machine as additional parameter (argv[3]) in your C program:

```
char temp[1024];
snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "ssh user@server \"echo %s | sudo -S -s \\$HOME/save.sh %s %s\"", argv[3], argv[1], argv[2]);
system((char *)temp);
```

-S for sudo means that password will be provided via stdin, so no user interaction should be needed. It's theoretical solution (I do not have time to check it - sorry) check it for your self & please tell as whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Which is the best way to trigger this script using sudo and not being prompted with root password?

You should redirect the stdin/stdout/stderr streams to do that so your program could talk to the target. This can't be done with `system()` which is a "shot-and-forget" solution.

But running your C program as root will remove the question and simplify the task.

Since your (client) program needs the credentials to use them at a given point, that may be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) use a [key with an empty passphrase](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~bigler/code/sshkeys.html), and add the public key to the remote `root` account's `authorized_keys`.

Comment: I have disabled the root ssh access for security reasons.. so I must either hardcode the password or find a way to remove the need of it. Tnx!